# interval keeps going after clearinterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a countdown timer in React. I have two buttons: "pause-resume" and "reset" with onClick event handlers. `clearInterval` doesn't work in either of them

Struggling to understand what is wrong

```
  let timer = {
  minutes: 25,
  seconds: 0}
  
  let [remainingTime, setTime] = useState(timer);
  let [paused, setPaused] = useState(true);

let counting

function handleClick(e) {
  const targetId = e.currentTarget.id

  if (targetId === 'pause-resume') {
      setTime(remainingTime = {...remainingTime, seconds: remainingTime.seconds === 0 ? 59 : remainingTime.seconds})
    if (paused === true) {
      setPaused(false)
      counting = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(remainingTime = {...remainingTime, seconds: remainingTime.seconds - 1})}, 1000)
    } else {
      clearInterval(counting)
      setPaused(true)
      
    }
  } else if (targetId === 'reset') {
    clearInterval(counting);
    setTime(timer)
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you declare `counting`? Unless you store it in a `ref` or state it will be redeclared on each render.

Comment: Make `counting` a `ref`

Comment: `setInterval` requires some specific juggling in React with hooks, use the implementation from https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks (which is also a very good explanation)

Comment: I've seen this exact implementation of setInterval without ref, but mine for some reason doesn't work. @AndyRay Ok, thank you I will look into that

Comment: @pilchard yeah, that was my problem, my `counting` was inside App component, thank you